# Attachment in Web-to-case using API

Tags: visualforce, api, web-to-case

Already gone through many different links and even a same question which suggests to use REST/SOAP API, i did a lot of things, create VF page and publish it on Site, created API but still not able to create attachment to case.

VF Page:

```
<head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var fileUpload = document.getElementsByName("fileUpload")[0];
                fileUpload.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log("hello");
                    var file =  document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[0];
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsText(file,"UTF-8");
                    reader.onload = function(e) {
                        document.getElementsByName("fileContent")
                        console.log(file);
                    }
                });

                var submit = document.getElementsByName("submit")[0];
                submit.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log("hello");
                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if(this.readyState == 4) {
                            console.log(this.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                    xhttp.open("POST", "/services/apexrest/Cases", true);
                    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
                    var orgid = document.getElementsByName("orgid")[0];
                    var retURL = document.getElementsByName("retURL")[0];
                    var Status = document.getElementsByName("Status")[0];
                    var Website_Name__c = document.getElementsByName("Website_Name__c")[0];
                    var Origin = document.getElementsByName("Origin")[0];
                    var CurrencyIsoCode = document.getElementsByName("CurrencyIsoCode")[0];
                    var name = document.getElementsByName("name")[0];
                    var email = document.getElementsByName("email")[0];
                    xhttp.send("name=aarya");
                    //xhttp.send("orgid="+orgid+"&retURL="+retURL+"&Status="+Status+"&Website_Name__c="+Website_Name__c+"&Origin="+Origin+"&CurrencyIsoCode="+CurrencyIsoCode+"&name="+name+"&email="+email);                    
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<form action="https://cs3.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
<label >Contact Name</label><input  id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text" /><br/>

            <label >Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br/>
            <label >Uplaod File</label><input type = "file"  id="fileUpload"  name="fileUpload"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

POST API:

```
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/Cases')
global with sharing class ContactUpMockup {

    @HttpPost
    global static ID postContactUs(String name) {
        Case thisCase = new Case(
            Status = 'Open',
            Website_Name__c = 'jardencs.com',
            RecordTypeId = '012d0000000wsrHAAQ',
            Origin = 'Web',
            CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD');
        insert thisCase;
        return thisCase.Id;
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you are using a VF page then you can use the standard case fields and built Attachment upload capability with Apex Controller. Check this [link](http://salesforceworld.blogspot.in/2011/06/save-attachment-in-apex.html) for uploading a file as an attachment. No need to use REST service.

Comment: I want to upload attachment on a vf page that is on my site.

Comment: Yes, you can add this VF page (in my answer) to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Salesforce [KNOWLEDGE ARTICLE](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000188389&type=1). 
As per the Question, your requirement align with first point.

Implement Visualforce pages in Force.com Sites. The VF page (may be with an Iframe ) would contain the standard Case fields you wish to include, in addition to an Attachment upload capability. Once saved, a new case record would be created in Salesforce with the related attachments.

With the above details, you can build a solution as below.

VF Page (Case Creation)

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="CaseControllerExt" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Create Case">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
                <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Subject}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Description}"/>
                <apex:inputFile accept="doc, txt, pdf" filename="{!fileName}" contentType="{!contentType}" value="{!afile}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!createCaseWithAttachment}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class CaseControllerExt {
    private final Case acase;
    public Blob afile {get; set;}
    public String contentType {get; set;}
    public String fileName {get; set;}
    public CaseControllerExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        this.acase=(Case)stdController.getRecord();
        acase.Status = 'Open';
        acase.Origin = 'Web';
    }
    public PageReference createCaseWithAttachment() {
        try{
            insert(acase);
        }catch(System.DMLException e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
        if(afile!=null){
            Attachment attach=new Attachment();
            attach.Body=afile;
            attach.Name=filename;
            attach.ContentType=contentType;
            attach.ParentID=acase.id;
            try {
                insert(attach);
            } catch(System.DMLException e) {
                ApexPages.addMessages(e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        PageReference p = Page.Confirmpage;
        p.setRedirect(true);
        return p;                    
    }        
}
```

VF Page (Confirmation)

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:pageMessages/>
     Your case has been successfully submitted.
</apex:page>
```