# How to attach a file in after insert trigger in Case object

Tags: after-trigger, web-to-case

I have a web to case form where users have the ability to attach files.Once a user attaches a file I read it in `javascript(fr.readAsText(fileTag.files[0]))` as Text and store it in a LongTextareafield. How to attach the file in after insert trigger to that particular Case? Can anybody suggest me how to do it?
I want the attachment to be displayed under the Files related tab of that particular case ?

Answer (score 0):

As you know Web To Case can not accept Attachments.

You can use SOAP/Rest API to insert attachments with cases, as mentioned in this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332973&type=1&mode=1) and you can try upvoting this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrhfAAC) that is present in idea exchange

For an implementation using rest API you can try using this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176180/attachment-in-web-to-case-using-api) for reference.